# Proof of a relation of elements in group rings

Tags: summation, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am reading the book *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Lawrence C. Washington*
and I need to prove certain identities for the orthogonal idempotents of a group ring (namely a,b,c,d in the attached image) which are left for the readers.

[image]

My approach to proving (a) $\varepsilon^2_\chi = \varepsilon_\chi$ is as follows:
\begin{align}
\varepsilon^2_\chi = \varepsilon_\chi \cdot \varepsilon_\chi = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{\sigma_1 \in G} \chi(\sigma_1){\sigma_1}^{-1} \cdot \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{\sigma_2 \in G} \chi(\sigma_2){\sigma_2}^{-1} = &\frac{1}{|G|^{2}} \sum_{\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in G} \chi(\sigma_1\sigma_2){\sigma_1}^{-1}{\sigma_2}^{-1}
\end{align}

How do I solve further?

I am not very good at dealing with multiple summations and that is the reason I am having difficulties in evaluating this sum. Please suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of times what you have to do with these is to reindex.  Here, try letting $\sigma_3=\sigma_2\sigma_1$, and add over $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_3$ instead.  The sum becomes $$\frac{1}{|G|^2}\displaystyle\sum_{\sigma_1,\sigma_3\in G}\chi(\sigma_3)\sigma_3^{-1}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\sigma_3\in G}\chi(\sigma_3)\sigma_3^{-1}=\varepsilon_{\chi}$$because $\chi(\sigma_1\sigma_2)=\chi(\sigma_2\sigma_1)$ and $(\sigma_2\sigma_1)^{-1}=\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2^{-1}$.

Comment: I could even conclude $\frac{1}{|G|^2}\displaystyle\sum_{\sigma_1,\sigma_3\in G}\chi(\sigma_3)\sigma_3^{-1}$. But I did not exactly understand how is it equal to $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\sigma_3\in G}\chi(\sigma_3)\sigma_3^{-1}=\varepsilon_{\chi}$.
Are there any gaps to fill or is it straight forward?

Comment: Since the sum doesn't depend on $\sigma_1$, it is just adding $|G|$ copies of the same thing, so that's why $\sigma_1$ goes away and $|G|$ cancels from the denominator.

Comment: Will the sum run over $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in G$ or $\sigma_1,\sigma_3 \in G$ in the first expression?

Comment: $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_3$.  I completely replaced $\sigma_2$ with $\sigma_3$, so there is no more $\sigma_2$ to worry about.

Comment: But $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ are related as $\sigma_3=\sigma_2\sigma_1$. Is it okay to replace $\sigma_2$ completely with $\sigma_3$?

Comment: Yes, because the transformation is reversible, and so when $\sigma_2$ runs over all elements of $G$, so does $\sigma_3$: If I want $\sigma_3$ to equal $g$, for example, I just have to take $\sigma_2=g\cdot\sigma_1^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay. It is clear now. Thank you very much!